# DFS in virtual graph with cycles

Tags: java, depth-first-search, traversal, graph-traversal, cyclic

Using a function that generates a list of "adjacent" values from an input value, i.e.

```
Function<Object, List<?>> adjacent;
```

one can "traverse" any "acyclic" collection of values as a virtual graph using, for example, `Depth-First Search (DFS)` in a non-recursive implementation.

```
public static void dfs(Object start, Function<Object, List<?>> adjacent) {
  Object current;
  List<?> children;
  ListIterator<?> iterator;
  Stack<Object> stack = new Stack<>();
  stack.push(start);
  while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    current = stack.pop();
    System.out.println(current.toString()); // Value "visited" 
    children = adjacent.apply(current);
    if (children == null) continue;
    iterator = children.listIterator(children.size());
    while (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
      stack.push(iterator.previous());
    }
  }
}
```

However, if there are any "cycles" in the collection (i.e., if any "child" value has as its own child a previously "visited" member of the collection, as determined by the `adjacent` function), the `dfs()` method above results in an infinite loop, since it does not mark already "visited" values as such.

Assuming that there is no way to modify the `adjacent` function, nor to trust the (whatever) implementation of `equals()/hashCode()` for the supplied values, each of which may be a new object, can there be any way of denoting "visited" values? Wrapping them in a new object with a boolean to mark "visited" values won't work, because the `adjacent` method will output generic values, not knowing whether they have been visited or not.

A simple `adjacent` method to test is, for example, `map::get`, with a map like

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put(0, Arrays.asList(1, 2));
map.put(1, Arrays.asList(3, 4));
map.put(3, Arrays.asList(1, 5));
```

Calling

```
dfs(0, map::get);
```

results in an infinite loop.

Comment: `map::get` returns a list so I don't expect `dfs(0, map::get);` to compile. Please provide an [mre].

Comment: The code works as is, including `map::get`, which is a Function<Object, List<Object>>. :-)

Comment: It does not compile with `Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map`

Comment: _ nor to trust the (whatever) implementation of equals()/hashCode()_ so does the question boils down to how do you know that two objects are equal without relaying on hashcode end equals ?

Comment: I modified the signature of the method to use `List<?>` for the `adjacent` Function, instead of `List<Object>`. It should compile now. Other than that yes, it is a matter of a proper `equals()/hashCode()` implementation, so that we can use a `Set<Object>` to mark visited nodes. So, either we assume that such an implementation exists, or an extra `Function<Object, Object>` will be needed, to provide a unique ID per "node"  visited, given that node. The question is really whether another solution exists, without requiring the above. Thanks.